# Safari on Mobile blocks window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a mobile page where the user creates there own smartphone backgrounds using textarea. I use html2canvas to translate the textarea into a canvas and windwow.open + canvas.toDataURL to open the PNG in a new tab for the user to save.
It works fine with Chrome but as far as I know Safari doesn't let me use window.open.
Is there any alternative how the user could download the PNG? I was thinking of maybe using the button which translates the textarea to link to an empty html file and also append the canvas to that empty html file? But I'm not sure how that would work.

Thank you very much in advance!

This is my JS at the moment:

```
$(function() { 
$("#buttononelandscape").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#testlandscape"), {


        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;

            window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));


        }

    });
});
```

});

Comment: *"...as far as I know Safari doesn't let me use window.open..."* What makes you say that? In my experience, `window.open` works fine on mobile Safari. Do you mean specifically with a `data:` URI?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You're right, yours does work... I will try to copy what you did there and see what happens!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're calling `window.open` indirectly, not in **direct** response to a user event. Most browsers will block those calls (I'm surprised Chrome isn't, but I don't know <s>a lot</s> basically anything about canvas rendering).

You may have to break up your logic into two buttons: One that generates the `data:` URI, then *another* that opens it as a new window, so that you can do the `window.open` in direct response to a user click.

If I do that, it works for me on Safari on the iPhone 5:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

and

```
document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
    var uri = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7";
    window.open(uri);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!